# Integral of absolute value of spin angular momentum of $N$-body system

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

There are $N$ particles moving freely in a plane. Let $J(t)$ be the spin angular momentum of the system of particles about its center of mass. (even center of mass keeps changing with time as particles move freely). Consider the integral $$I = \int_0^T |J|dt$$ What is the physical significance of $I$?

Comment: It looks like a time-average to me where the $\frac{1}{T}$ has been forgotten.

Comment: Look at the absolute sign, its not time average exactly.